# Dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server

This is my query... but it returns incorrect syntax near '+'

```
 DECLARE @refKlinik_id INT
SET @refKlinik_id  = 24

DECLARE @kriter VARCHAR(50)

IF @refKlinik_id <=0 
BEGIN
  SET @kriter = ''
END
ELSE
    SET @Kriter =  'AND H.refKlinik_id =' + @refKlinik_id

SELECT        H.adi + ' ' + H.soyadi AS Hasta, H.tcKimlikNo, CONVERT(varchar, H.dogumTarihi, 103) AS DogumTarihi, K.kisaAdi AS Klinik, A.acikAdres + A.ilce + A.il AS Adres,
                          A.tel1, A.gsm, CASE H.hastaKartiVar WHEN 1 THEN 'Hasta Kartı Sahibi' WHEN 0 THEN 'Hasta Kartı Yok' WHEN NULL 
                         THEN 'Hasta Kartı Yok' END AS HastaKartiDurumu
FROM            Hastalar AS H INNER JOIN
                         Klinikler AS K ON K.klinik_id = H.refKlinik_id INNER JOIN
                         Adresler AS A ON A.refHasta_id = H.hasta_id
WHERE        (K.refKlinikGrup_id = 1) AND (H.durumu = 1) + @kriter + AND (A.aktif = 1)
ORDER BY H.adi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using dynamic sql correctly - you have to concatenate the query into a varchar/nvarchar variable and then execute that.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @MyParam INTEGER
SET @MyParam = 1

DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @nSQL = 'SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField = @MyParam'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @nSQL, N'@MyParam INTEGER', @MyParam
```

Be careful with dynamic sql, this approach I've exampled is preferred over just concatenating the @MyParam directly on to the string as it helps guard against SQL injection.

In your case, you don't actually need to use dynamic SQL, you could do:

```
DECLARE @refKlinik_id INT
SET @refKlinik_id  = 24

SELECT        H.adi + ' ' + H.soyadi AS Hasta, H.tcKimlikNo, CONVERT(varchar, H.dogumTarihi, 103) AS DogumTarihi, K.kisaAdi AS Klinik, A.acikAdres + A.ilce + A.il AS Adres,
                          A.tel1, A.gsm, CASE H.hastaKartiVar WHEN 1 THEN 'Hasta Kartı Sahibi' WHEN 0 THEN 'Hasta Kartı Yok' WHEN NULL 
                         THEN 'Hasta Kartı Yok' END AS HastaKartiDurumu
FROM            Hastalar AS H INNER JOIN
                         Klinikler AS K ON K.klinik_id = H.refKlinik_id INNER JOIN
                         Adresler AS A ON A.refHasta_id = H.hasta_id
WHERE        (K.refKlinikGrup_id = 1) AND (H.durumu = 1) AND (@refKlinik_id<=0 OR H.refKlinik_id = @refKlinik_id) AND (A.aktif = 1)
ORDER BY H.adi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate @kriter into the rest of the where clause like that - it's evaluating it as a string, not a piece of SQL. You'd have to put the whole thing in a string variable and then use Exec

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 DECLARE @refKlinik_id INT
declare @query varchar(1000)
SET @refKlinik_id  = 24

DECLARE @kriter VARCHAR(50)

IF @refKlinik_id <=0 
BEGIN
  SET @kriter = ''
END
ELSE
    SET @Kriter =  'AND H.refKlinik_id =' + cast(@refKlinik_id as varchar(10))

set @query='SELECT        H.adi + '' '' + H.soyadi AS Hasta, H.tcKimlikNo, CONVERT(varchar, H.dogumTarihi, 103) AS DogumTarihi, K.kisaAdi AS Klinik, A.acikAdres + A.ilce + A.il AS Adres,
                          A.tel1, A.gsm, CASE H.hastaKartiVar WHEN 1 THEN ''Hasta Kartı Sahibi'' WHEN 0 THEN ''Hasta Kartı Yok'' WHEN NULL 
                         THEN ''Hasta Kartı Yok'' END AS HastaKartiDurumu
FROM            Hastalar AS H INNER JOIN
                         Klinikler AS K ON K.klinik_id = H.refKlinik_id INNER JOIN
                         Adresler AS A ON A.refHasta_id = H.hasta_id
WHERE        (K.refKlinikGrup_id = 1) AND (H.durumu = 1)' + @kriter + 'AND (A.aktif = 1)
ORDER BY H.adi'
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest before typing a single character of Dynamic SQL that you familiarise yourself with the following "essential reading".

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Then if you have any questions about the content just let me know.